# html changes not reflecting without hard refresh

Tags: html, caching, browser

Frequently HTML text updates are not reflecting in users browser. So i need to ask user to clear cache every-time.
I am not asking about CSS or JS. My problem is related to HTML updates only.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it just a plain `.html` file? Are you using a local server, or just serving files via the filesystem?

Comment: I have had this happen to me with css or js only but not `.html` files. But I think it depends on what you are using to save your .html files. It is the only probability, that I can think of right now.

Comment: Check your site on other system...if its not reflecting there also then try to check if you have development mode on in your ssl provider site...clear cached data from there...if its not working only on specific system then check the browser versions, update if possible...this may help

Comment: @Mav i serving files from node server

Comment: @exabytes.js its happening for all of my users who already opens my app in there browser not for one or two systems.

Comment: @AkshayKumar check this out for node : https://stackoverflow.com/a/38295516/9144250