# Problem not updating the JavaScript file when refreshing the page using npm http-server

Tags: javascript, node.js, httpserver

My problem is new and I didn't have it before, as I use http-sever package to make localhost for my projects. The problem is that when I modify the JavaScript file or any other file, and I do a refresh of the page ctrl + r, this package does not see the JavaScript file and does not update the old file.

And in order to solve the problem, I have to turn off http-sever, then manipulate the port, and then run the http-sever in order to update the JavaScript file and show it in the command line!

So what is the cause of the problem?

---

Modify :

The result that should be in the file on every page refresh:

```
[2022-08-25T19:10:29.858Z] "GET /pages/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:104.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/104.0" [2022-08-25T19:10:31.460Z] "GET /pages/home.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:104.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/104.0" [2022-08-25T19:10:31.539Z] "GET /css/css/fontello-embedded.css" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:104.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/104.0" [2022-08-25T19:10:31.546Z] "GET /css/project.css" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:104.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/104.0" [2022-08-25T19:10:31.548Z] "GET /css/css/normalize.css" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:104.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/104.0" [2022-08-25T19:10:31.558Z] "GET /css/css/slick.css" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:104.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/104.0" [2022-08-25T19:10:31.593Z] "GET /js/tools/html5shiv.min.js" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:104.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/104.0" [2022-08-25T19:10:31.603Z] "GET /js/project.js" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:104.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/104.0" [2022-08-25T19:10:31.609Z] "GET /js/tools/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:104.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/104.0" [2022-08-25T19:10:31.611Z] "GET /js/tools/jquery.countdown.min.js" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:104.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/104.0" [2022-08-25T19:10:31.613Z] "GET /js/tools/slick.min.js" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:104.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/104.0" [2022-08-25T19:10:31.688Z] "GET /images/header/logo.png" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:104.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/104.0" [2022-08-25T19:10:31.699Z] "GET /images/page-01/part-01/01.png" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:104.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/104.0" [2022-08-25T19:10:31.712Z] "GET /images/page-01/part-01/02.png" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:104.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/104.0" [2022-08-25T19:10:31.720Z] "GET /images/page-01/part-02/01.jpg" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:104.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/104.0" [2022-08-25T19:10:31.726Z] "GET /images/page-01/part-04/week.png" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:104.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/104.0" [2022-08-25T19:10:31.734Z] "GET /images/page-01/part-05/01.jpg" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:104.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/104.0" [2022-08-25T19:10:31.745Z] "GET /images/page-01/part-05/02.jpg" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:104.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/104.0" [2022-08-25T19:10:31.761Z] "GET /images/page-01/part-05/03.jpg" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:104.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/104.0" [2022-08-25T19:10:31.769Z] "GET /images/page-01/part-05/05.jpg" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:104.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/104.0" [2022-08-25T19:10:31.774Z] "GET /images/page-01/part-05/06.jpg" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:104.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/104.0" [2022-08-25T19:10:31.776Z] "GET /images/page-01/part-05/04.jpg" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:104.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/104.0" [2022-08-25T19:10:31.779Z] "GET /images/page-01/part-06/01.jpg" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:104.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/104.0" [2022-08-25T19:10:31.783Z] "GET /images/page-01/part-02/02.jpg" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:104.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/104.0" [2022-08-25T19:10:31.785Z] "GET /images/page-01/part-02/03.jpg" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:104.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/104.0" [2022-08-25T19:10:31.800Z] "GET /images/page-01/part-03/01.jpg" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:104.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/104.0" [2022-08-25T19:10:31.805Z] "GET /images/page-01/part-03/02.jpg" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:104.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/104.0" [2022-08-25T19:10:31.814Z] "GET /images/page-01/part-03/03.jpg" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:104.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/104.0" [2022-08-25T19:10:31.819Z] "GET /images/page-01/part-03/04.jpg" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:104.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/104.0" [2022-08-25T19:10:31.845Z] "GET /images/page-01/part-03/05.jpg" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:104.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/104.0" [2022-08-25T19:10:31.865Z] "GET /images/page-01/part-03/06.jpg" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:104.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/104.0" [2022-08-25T19:10:31.867Z] "GET /images/page-01/part-03/08.jpg" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:104.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/104.0" [2022-08-25T19:10:31.870Z] "GET /images/page-01/part-03/07.jpg" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:104.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/104.0" [2022-08-25T19:10:31.879Z] "GET /images/page-01/part-06/02.jpg" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:104.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/104.0" [2022-08-25T19:10:31.882Z] "GET /images/page-01/part-06/03.jpg" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:104.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/104.0" [2022-08-25T19:10:31.885Z] "GET /images/footer/logo.png" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:104.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/104.0" [2022-08-25T19:10:31.887Z] "GET /images/footer/payment.png" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:104.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/104.0" [2022-08-25T19:10:47.091Z] "GET /images/page-02/01.jpg" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:104.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/104.0" [2022-08-25T19:10:47.097Z] "GET /images/page-02/03.jpg" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:104.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/104.0"
```

The result that shows me:

```
[2022-08-25T19:18:06.718Z] "GET /pages/shopping-cart.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:104.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/104.0"
```

---

Modify 2 :

The results that appear to me when activating this package

```
`D:\project-1\dest
λ http-server
Starting up http-server, serving ./

http-server version: 14.1.1

http-server settings:
CORS: disabled
Cache: 3600 seconds
Connection Timeout: 120 seconds
Directory Listings: visible
AutoIndex: visible
Serve GZIP Files: false
Serve Brotli Files: false
Default File Extension: none

Available on:
http://192.168.1.10:8080
http://127.0.0.1:8080
Hit CTRL-C to stop the server`
```

---

Modify 3 :

I have tried to delete the package from the device by using the command

```
npm uninstall -g http-server
```

And reinstall it by command

```
npx http-server
```

And the problem still exists!

---

Note:

- npm version: v12.18.3
- Package version: v14.1.1

Comment: I use the http-server project frequently, and I can tell you that it will serve fresh content. The problem must be something special about the way you are configuring or running http-server, or producing the final javascript asset. Or perhaps there is something about your other content that's leading to caching or something. The info you've shared is not enough to debug the problem.

Comment: Excellent. Tell me what information should I attach so that you can get the cause of the problem? Shall I take a picture of the command line page for you when activating this package?

Comment: I have modified the question and added additional information

Comment: Perhaps you should change the cache setting. You currently have it set to cache for an hour.

Comment: Well, tell me how to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. The solution was simply that I  disable the cache and at the same time add a port via the -p shortcut, and this is the problem that in all the previous solutions that were talking only about deleting the cache without adding a port after deleting

So the code for the solution is:

```
npx http-server -c-1 -p 8081
```

**8081** is just for testing and frankly I like the number and I want to use it always

Thanks [tom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/814463/tom) and [Jhow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19804065/jhow) for the help

---

Note: This solution was taken from this question

- [node http-server not serving updated html files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38295463/node-http-server-not-serving-updated-html-files)

specifically from the best answer.

---

I advise you to see the discussion that took place in the best answer.